# What is the best data conversion method to use in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to convert a value to a different datatype in sql. And as I know I can use any of the `CONVERT`, `TRY_CONVERT`, `PARSE` and `TRY_PARSE` built in functions for that.

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),'12');

SELECT 
    TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),'12');

SELECT 
    PARSE('12' AS DECIMAL(18,2));

SELECT 
    TRY_PARSE('12' AS DECIMAL(18,2));
SELECT 
    CAST('12' AS DECIMAL(18,2));
```

What I need to clarify is, among the above mentioned methods, **performance wise** what is the best method to convert some value to a different data type?

Comment: Benchmark each one and find out.  You have all the tools you need to answer this question yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets just talk about Convert, Cast and Parse to compare performance as others are just a variant of these.

`CONVERT` is SQL Server specific, `CAST` is ANSI.

`CONVERT` is more flexible in that you can format dates etc. Other than that, they are pretty much the same. If you don't care about the extended features, use CAST.

`PARSE` function is not a native Sql function, instead it is a `.NET Framework` Common Language Run-time dependent function. Then obviously it will have the performance overhead and also requires the presence of .NET CLR on the database Server. Continue to use the existing CAST and CONVERT functions wherever it is possible.

For SQL Server: GENERALLY I will say- `CONVERT` is your guy.

Refer to the link below if you are have a specific datatype to convert. Example has `TRY_PARSE` and `TRY_CONVERT` as well.

Reference: [Performance comparison on large data set](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3018/performance-comparison-of-the-sql-server-parse-cast-convert-and-tryparse-trycast-tryconvert-functions/)

Answer (score 2):

This is just a benchmark test;

```
declare @val DECIMAL(18,2);
declare @now datetime, @then datetime
DECLARE @intFlag INT

SET @intFlag = 1
select @then = getdate()
WHILE (@intFlag <=200000) begin
    set @val = CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),'12');
    SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
end
select @now = getdate()
print('CONVERT: ' + convert(varchar(50), datediff(millisecond, @then, @now)))

SET @intFlag = 1
select @then = getdate()
WHILE (@intFlag <=200000) begin
    Set @val = TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),'12');
    SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
end
select @now = getdate()
print('TRY_CONVERT: ' + convert(varchar(50), datediff(millisecond, @then, @now)))

--for other type of "conversion" also not including here....
```

Here is the `OutPut`:

```
CONVERT: 106
TRY_CONVERT: 110
PARSE: 4726
TRY_PARSE: 4736
CAST: 106
```